# Extract the last item which matches the condition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, where I am checking for a boolean property, I need to get the last one from the array of objects which is true and need to get the name property.

This is what I have done, is there any better approach  or simple way to achieve this:

```js
const a = [{is_done: true, name: 'a'}, {is_done: true, name: 'b'}, {is_done: false, name: 'c'}]


let output = a.filter(a => a.is_done).slice(-1)[0].name


console.log(output)
```

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-find-from-last

Comment: Better? Simpler? Shorter? More efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by first applying `reverse` and then using `find` which will return the first item which corresponds to the condition you specify.

Please note that you would probably want to apply the reverse method on a copy of a string and not on the original so it's better to use `[...a]` as
hjrshng commented below.

```js
const a = [{is_done: true, name: 'a'}, {is_done: true, name: 'b'}, {is_done: false, name: 'c'}]

const res = [...a].reverse().find(x => x.is_done);

console.log(res.name)
```

Please also note that in the near future, you will be able to use `findLast` and `findLastIndex` which are currently in stage 3 - https://github.com/tc39/proposals

Comment: ```reverse()``` will mutate the original array, you should write ```[...a].reverse()```

Comment: Thanks for this comment @hjrshng . I will modify my answer